# Assigning a Date Field from a List to a String Variable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to retrieve a date field value from a List and store it into a string variable as part of the an ItemAdded EventReceiver.

In the example below both ItemManager and stringSubject get set correctly but when the stringStartDate is being assigned the following error is generated:

"NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I just need to know how to assign the List date field to a string variable?

Thanks

```
 foreach (SPListItem item in myCustomList.Items)
               {
                   string ItemManager = item["Manager"].ToString();
                   string stringSubject = item["Subject"].ToString();
                   string stringStartDate = item["StartDate"].ToString;
               }
```

Comment: Best answer will need to know the data type of item["StartDate"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `item["StartDate"]` is a `DateTime?` you can do something like this:

```
string stringStartDate = (item["StartDate"] as DateTime?).HasValue ? 
    item["StartDate"].ToString() : 
    string.Empty;
```

You also missed `()` off the end of `ToString()`.

Obviously, you may want to replace `string.Empty` with some other value such as `DateTime.Now.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - excellent.  Does exactly what I require.  Thankyou for your help.